# Error in xml document (1, 2) ... was not expected

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've tried several of the suggestions found on other SO answers for this same error but nothing has helped. Adding a namespace attr, using a blank namespace attr. Loading the string into an xmlDocument then rewriting it back to an xmlWriter. Using Serialazble instead of DataContract. Using xmlRoot attr with and without a namespace. Nothing works! Help.

I'm trying to instantiate a FillRequestExtended with the constructor that accepts an xml formatted string and always get the error Error in xml document (1, 2)

The Inner Exception reads: "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WdRx.Exactus.Objects'> was not expected."

The class looks like so:

```
namespace WdRx.Exactus.Objects
{

    [DataContract]
    public class FillRequestExtended : IExtendedData
    {

        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement]
        public KeyValuePair<string, string>[] Properties { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement]
        public List<Payment> PaymentItems { get; set; }

        public FillRequestExtended()
        {
        }

        public FillRequestExtended(string xml)
        {
            FillRequestExtended extendedData;

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FillRequestExtended));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
                extendedData = (FillRequestExtended)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            Properties = extendedData.Properties;
            PaymentItems = new List<Payment>(extendedData.PaymentItems);
        }

    }

}
```

The string passed in is serialized elsewhere with no issue and looks like so:

```
<FillRequestExtended xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WdRx.Exactus.Objects\"
                     xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
  <PaymentItems>
    <Payment>
      <Amount>-43.95</Amount>
      <Summary>CCP PAYMENT - AUTH:014910</Summary>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
      <Amount>0.00</Amount>
      <Summary>Type: VIS   Account: ************5793   Expires: 05/16   Authorization: 014910</Summary>
    </Payment>
  </PaymentItems>
  <Properties xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
      <a:key>RxDcDate</a:key>
      <a:value>20150414</a:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
      <a:key>RefillStatus</a:key>
      <a:value>PROFILED</a:value>
    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
  </Properties>
</FillRequestExtended>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two different XML deserializers.  By decorating the class with [DataContract] you are forcing it to use the WCF serializer.  In the deserialize code, you are using the normal XML object deserializer.